# Caching duration in Flutter using the plugin cached_network_image?

Tags: flutter, caching, duration

I'm using the flutter plugin [`cached_network_image:`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) and would like to know, how long the caching duration is for the cached files?
Also if there is a way to modify the caching duration to x-days?

What I also would like to know is, if the files are cached in the original file format or if it gets converted? e.g. `*.HEIC -> *.JPEG`

Currently I'm simply caching calling: `CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: snapshot.data))`

or see below....

```java
...return FutureBuilder(
                      future: FireStorageService.downloadImageFromStorage(
                          context, snapshot.data.items[index].fullPath),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                          return GridTile(
                            child: Card(
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: snapshot.data)),
                          );
                        }
                        return Container();
                      },
                    );
...
```

While searching for an answer regarding my questions above, I got faced with the plugin [`flutter_cache_manager:`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) and saw the Type `Duration(days: 7)`

If this (using `flutter_cache_manage:`) is the only way to modify the caching duration, how can I use that in my case?

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`CachedNetworkImage` can receive a parameter called `cacheManager`. That means that you can give a custom `CacheManager` to  your `CachedNetworkImage` First of all you should add [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) to your pubspec.yaml. Then you can add something like this:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: snapshot.data,
  cacheManager: CacheManager(
    Config(
      'cacheKey',
      stalePeriod: Duration(days: 7),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Replace the duration with your wanted duration and the cache key with any `String` you want. Add other parameters to the `Config` object if needed.

Just to note, the duration of the cache is 7 days (in this example) from the last use of the cached file, not from the download date.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information - it works perfect :)

Comment: This answer is not complete, `CacheManager` should be used as a singleton. Otherwise you would create a seperate cacheManager for every different image you fetched. The application size will be enormous in a mid size image density app. And memory usage will be more than needed. Please create your own cache manager using singleton for your specific need, here is an example from the original lib: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cache_manager/blob/32b71c1da1689b97434959ac407b03b74d7e405c/flutter_cache_manager/lib/src/cache_managers/default_cache_manager.dart#L6-L16